# can't see site on network but can see it locally

Tags: apache, unix, centos, virtualhost

I have added a virtual host container in my httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/dev_sites/site
ServerName site.aa.local
</VirtualHost>
```

In my /etc/hosts file on my server computer it is:

```
127.0.0.1 site.aa.local
```

If I go to site.aa.local on my machine I can see my site. However if I go to that same address on another computer on my network it doesn't find the page. However, if I do aa.local it finds that. Any idea why a computer on my network can't see it?

I'm on a centos machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site.aa.local` points to your loopback interface in your machine. Just in case: it's a virtual interface that is only accessible from your machine by definition.

For that name to work in another computer, `site.aa.local` should point to your machine's LAN IP address (either via /etc/hosts or DNS) and the Apache server in your computer should be listening in all interfaces (it most likely is).

Try adding `YOUR_LAN_IP site.aa.local` to the `/etc/hosts` file in the other computer, or just visit YOUR_LAN_IP if that is the Apache default virtual host (that is, if it's the only one or the first defined).

Comment: I took your advice about adding myip site.aa.local to /etc/hosts...but I have to do that to all my computers on my network. Is there a way to do this in apache so it is a global change?

Comment: No, you'd have to set up a DNS server and configure all machines to use it. If you don't want to do that you're probably better off just using the IP itself to access your site, and configuring Apache so this is the default virtual host.